# How to find out if n! can be expressed as a multiplication of three consecutive numbers?

Tags: c++

Hey I have gotten this far with my code

```
    #include
    using namespace std;
```

`int factorial(int n);
int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial(n);

    return 0;
}
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n > 1)
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}`

Now I need to check if the factorial can be a multiplication of three consecutive numbers, and I am really stuck on that, thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: why are you stuck? Start with checking if the number is equal to `1 * 2 * 3` then try the next set of consecutive numbers continue till you found such factors or you dont. Then try to find out what is the biggest numbers you have to check. Optionally try to find a better first guess than `1 * 2* 3`

Comment: Loop through all possible number from 1 to n and find out which one is matching and if it finds one... break the loop...

Comment: do you check it with a for loop?

Comment: you need to know what you want to do before deciding whether you use a for loop or whatever. If you dont know how to solve it on paper you dont need to start writing code

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, or how this is related to C++. What do you need to check? If there is any `a > 1` such that `n! == (a - 2) * (a - 1) * a`?

Comment: Note that since factorials grow very quickly, and there's a limit to the values an `int` can store, your `factorial` function will overflow for many values.  Assuming `int` has 32 bits, `factorial(n)` will only be valid for `n<13`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that except for `3!`, `4!` or `5!` there are such numbers.

Still, if you want to look for these numbers:

```
int hint = std::pow(fact, 1./3.);
for (int trial = -10;, trial < 11; ++trial)
{
    // check if (hint + trial - 1) * (hint + trial) * (hint + trial + 1) is equal to your result
}
```

I use 21 values to check, it's too much, but it's the idea.

Comment: There is `6! = 8 * 9 * 10` too: https://wandbox.org/permlink/etgyGs8REtbehw6U